# How do you trace execution of a Camunda process?

Tags: java, bpmn, business-process-management, camunda, bpmn.io

I want to use the bpmn.io JS framework to display the flow of in-progress and completed processes, where completed tasks and the connections that were followed are highlighted a certain color, current task is another color, and failed tasks are highlighted yet another color.

This is easy enough to do with the GUI/JS frontend, but I can't figure out how to get the execution path out of the Java API. I'm embedding the Camunda library in our own Java application and can provide an API that exposes this info, but I'm at a loss as to how to collect the information. How do I collect it?

Comment: Have you tried the rest api of the task list and engine?